# IMPORT XML function - Stock Price - Google Sheets

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets

I'm trying to import the value of an ETF stock using IMPORTXML via Google Sheets. From the URL : https://www.justetf.com/en/etf-profile.html?isin=DE000A1DCTL3. What I have so far:

=IMPORTXML("https://www.justetf.com/en/etf-profile.html?isin=DE000A1DCTL3","//div[@class='col-xs-6']/div[@class='val']")

This outputs:

EUR 141.56
EUR 2,932 m
0.15% p.a.

[google sheets image view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7Usf.png)

I would only like the Value of 141.56 to be output to the cell but I am unsure how to do this. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.justetf.com/en/etf-profile.html?isin=DE000A1DCTL3","//div[@class='col-xs-6']/div[@class='val']/span[2]")
```